ASP.NET Core 8 Identity: External Authentication Fails Across Different Domains
I'm working on an application that needs to authenticate users using external providers (like Google) through my ASP.NET Core 8 Web API usings Identity.
My code works perfectly when the webapp and the API are on the same domain:
The Angular app calls the challenge endpoint, the user is redirected to Google, does its business, Google redirects to the return URL specified on the Angular app with the Identity.External cookie set and finally, the Angular app calls the /external-login-callback with { withCredentials: true } and obtain a bearer token.
But I need to handle the case where this isn't the case, when the front-end and the API are on different domain like a mobile application or just a web application on another domain.
When it's on a different domain, I always get a 401 Unauthorized because GetExternalLoginInfoAsync is always null. Indeed, the cookie is set only on the API domain but not on the domain of the Angular application calling the API.
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

            builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseInMemoryDatabase("AppDb"));

            builder.Services.AddIdentityApiEndpoints<IdentityUser>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

            builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddGoogle(x =>
                {
                    x.SignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
                    x.ClientId = builder.Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"]!;
                    x.ClientSecret = builder.Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"]!;
                });

            builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
            builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
            builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

            builder.Services.AddCors(x =>
            {
                x.AddDefaultPolicy(y =>
                {
                    y.AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowCredentials()
                    .SetIsOriginAllowed(_ => true);
                });
            });

            var app = builder.Build();

            app.UseCors();

            app.MapGet("/external-login", (SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager, [FromQuery] string redirectUrl, [FromQuery] string externalProvider = "Google") =>
            {
                return Results.Challenge(
                    authenticationSchemes: [externalProvider.ToString()],
                    properties: signInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(
                        externalProvider.ToString(),
                        redirectUrl
                    )
                );
            });

            app.MapGet("/external-login-callback", async (UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager, SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager) =>
            {
                signInManager.AuthenticationScheme = IdentityConstants.BearerScheme;

                var info = await signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();

                if (info == null) // Always null when API and front-end are on different domain
                {
                    return Results.Unauthorized();
                }

                var externalSignInResult = await signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(
                    info.LoginProvider,
                    info.ProviderKey,
                    isPersistent: false);

                // ... authentication logic ...
                return Results.Empty;
            });

            app.Run();
        }
    }

Do you have any idea how I can manage this? Or a workaround?

If you are inside the different domain which means the two site couldn't share cookie, you should use subdomain to still let two application keep the cookie.
